# Clear dynamic allocated data with signal

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, signals

What is the correct way to clean with `free()` dynamic allocated data in C when using signal?

[Here](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/signal/kill.html) there's an example with shared memory, and the used solution is to declare global variable, but seems not very clean and secure.

This is an example code with an array of structure dynamically allocated not corretly cleaned

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include  <signal.h>

typedef struct {
    int val;
} mystruct_t;

void sigquit(int sig) {
    signal(sig, SIG_IGN);
    printf("Child killed\n");

    // Clear the dynamic allocated data inside
    // the signal quit method
    //
    // int i;
    // for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    //     free(struct_a[i]);
    // }
    // free(struct_a);

    exit(0);
}

int
main()
{
    int n = 10;
    /* dynamic allocated array of structure */
    mystruct_t **struct_a = generatearray(n);
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        printf("Child process. My pid is %d and my parent's id is %d.\n",
            getpid(), getppid());

        if (signal(SIGQUIT, sigquit) == SIG_ERR) {
            printf("SIGINT install error\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        while(1);
    }
    else {
        printf("Parent process. My pid is %d and my parent's id is %d.\n",
            getpid(), pid);

        sleep(1);
        kill(pid, SIGQUIT);
        sleep(5);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Which method you would use to solve this problem?

Comment: In real code it's likely the child process would have an event loop using `select` or some other similar mechanism. Then the general procedure is for the signal handler just to set a flag. The event loop would then detect this and do the process clean up and exit at that point (outside the signal handler).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to POSIX, neither `malloc()` nor `free()` nor any of the other high-level memory allocation functions are signal-safe (`mmap()` and friends are though). You cannot call them safely in a signal handler as they are not required to survive being called from a signal handler.

The typical workaround is to set a flag in the signal handler that memory shall be cleared. The main loop of your program checks for this flag periodically and does the desired action when the flag is found to be set. Use the type `sig_atomic_t` for this variable and declare it as `volatile` for maximum safety.

Answer (score 2):

Have the signal handler set a variable of type `sig_atomic_t`. In your regular code, periodically check for that variable to be set and, if so, shut down cleanly. Clean shutdown, if required, must be designed into a piece of software. It can't be "stapled on" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike shared memory most other resources (like sockets and malloced memory) do not require cleanup before program exit. This is because they are cleaned-up anyways after the process is terminated.

Setting a flag that will be processed in your main loop is a good idea for other signals, but will not work as expected for `SIGQUIT` because your process will be already terminated after the signal handler is called.